# Granted privileges without reputation

Tags: support, notifications, privileges

Today I noticed in my inbox that I had been granted several privileges, for which I don't have the reputation necessary.  I still can't perform the functions allowed by the privileges, and my reputation has not increased.  I have a feeling this may be a bug, but I'm not sure.  Has this happened to anyone else?

The messages I received are as follows:

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege – create wiki posts learn more
>   Congrats, you've gained the privilege – participate in meta learn more
>   Congrats, you've gained the privilege – vote up learn more
>   Congrats, you've gained the privilege – flag posts learn more
>   Congrats, you've gained the privilege – remove new user restrictions
>   learn more

Comment: Did you have a question or answer that was upvoted/accepted giving you the reputation for those privileges and then deleted causing you to lose that reputation?

Comment: Not that I'm aware; the only thing I can think of is that I posted an answer that was downvoted and then upvoted shorty after, but being rep 1 I never saw any reputation change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably one of your answer was accepted then unaccepted so you got notifications regarding privileges upto 15 reputations.

That's why your [today's reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2489497/caleb-brinkman?tab=reputation) tab showing 0 reputation as reputation changes.

Comment: Ah that makes sense; I think that may be exactly what happened, because I recommended another user's answer.  I guess I never saw it get accepted.